# Network Partition in RabbitMQ

Tags: networking, rabbitmq, partitioning

I am trying to analyze how RabbitMQ Partition theorum(**pause_minority**,**pause_if_all_down**,**autoheal**) work? I have reproduced the network partition in three-node clusters in GCP but **I was unable to conclude which node will be stopped when there is a network jitter in between them**.

I have used [perftest](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-perf-test/stable/htmlsingle/) for creating a production-like environment and used iptables concept in order to bring partition between two nodes.
I created ten queues with replication factor 2(master and one slave) and was using **min_master** for the uniform distribution of queues.
Publishing rate was 1000/sec(100/sec for each queue)
Consumption rate was 1000/sec(100/sec for each queue)

Please see the test results here for [Pause_Minority](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERdyp.png)

**Explanation**: Taking the first row, 8,9, and 6 are the connections(before partition) on Node A, B, and C respectively. I have blacklisted Node A with B and the results are Node A and Node B stopped running and connections are transferred to Node C.
I got different results for rows 2 and 3(Please See the Linked Image)

Please see the test results here [pause_if_all_down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF09z.png)

**Note**:0 Connections means (no publishing and consumption)

Please see the test results here [autoheal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA1SS.png)

For **Pause Minority** I read [this](https://www.tavisca.com/blog/handling-rabbitmq-network-partition-in-aws/) article in which the author has explained the master  slave architecture but I was unable to get the resutls as per the blog.
I am also attaching the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZCT18tOCJVLl96v7190Ob0pDyngLbk_kkwL9nSEZjT4/edit#gid=0) for the google sheet where I have shared the resuts of my test in detail
**Other Artciles** that I have read are as listed:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/partitions.html
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tanzu-RabbitMQ-for-Kubernetes/1.2/tanzu-rmq/GUID-partitions.html

Can anyone explain to me how partiton theorums decide which node will be stopped in case of partition? Does it decide on the basis of a number of queues, or no of connections, or anything else?